# Are the diplomacy actions (trade etc) only available from the leader meeting screen?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civ5, I find that I pretty much can't stand the new leader meeting screens. Obviously, if one wants to trade one has to open up this screen.

Or do I?

Is it possible to initiate trade agreements from the diplomacy overview dialog?

Comment: Have you messed with the quality settings for the leader screens? My friend has all the settings on the lowest, and the leader screen is just a static image - not a rendered scene. Not a direct answer, but you might find that less irritating?

Comment: @DMA : CHeers, It's loading fast and I don't mind the animation. My "problem" is that it breaks the feel of the game UI IMHO. Civ4 has a *great* UI where *everything* fits together -- seems they had to break it again in Civ5 :-)

Comment: Since that seems to have helped I'll upgrade my comment to an answer.

Comment: @DMA : *lol* - communication is a hard thing to get right. What I meant to say was: "Thanks, but it's already loading fast, even with the animation, and I do not mind if the leader is animated or not so I'll just leave it at the animated default". Anyway - I accepted your answer since it's probably right on the point that there's nothing we can do about it until (if) they release a patch. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried lowering the quality settings for the leader screens?

I believe this will make the screens performance much better, but instead of a fully live-rendered scene you get just a static pre-rendered image of the leader. So, even if your computer doesn't need the performance boost, you might find this preferable if you find the leader interaction irritating.

However, the screen still appears in exactly the same format, and I'm not aware of there being another method to communicate.